# MongoDB collection _id field as hashed or create index

Tags: mongodb, hash, objectid

I'm creating a MongoDB with a collection that includes objects that, for instance, are like:

```
{ name: "myname",
  description: {
     key1: "hi",
     key2: "h12"
  }
}
```

The objects are gonna be searchable by the "name" which will be unique, so I want to know which solution is better:

1. Let MongoDB handle ObjectId creation and search by name without any index.
2. Create _id as binary_hash_function(name). How can I store this hash as a binary or number so it can be quickly searchable?
3. Create an hashed index linked to name and then search by name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of Mongodb is it index objectId field. As you say name  will be unique.So its better to keep name as ObjectId. It will be unique and indexed.[refer](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/)

Comment: The idea is that I'm not searching by _id but from name, so I want the collection to be indexed by name or hash of it, somehow

Comment: if you use _id field for name, then you no need for separate field and index for name right?

Comment: you are right. But I cannot change the original schema.

Comment: Then create a field as name , index the name field with unique option.